# How is it possible for a user to start a bounty with low reputation?

Tags: support, bounties, privileges

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35514733/wait-until-a-click-event-has-been-fired-c-sharp) question, the guy who started the bounty has only 36 reputation. It would mean that he had 86 prior to the bounty, which is below the limit for the action.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 7):

You can already offer bounties from [75 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties), not 100. So everything is in order.

Comment: I could swear it was 100 or even 150... I guess I stand corrected. Thanks!